# Highstock clipPath calculation bug

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I faced with the problem in Highstock (Highcharts). When crop property is set to true (default value) for series, there is case when crop area is not updated/recalculated.

The bug appears every time we create a new axis with height A, change it's height to B, remove it and create a new one with height A again with the same ID. The created axis is cropped with clipPath of removed axis.

Simplistically, the logic looks like:

```
chart.addAxis({..., id: Y_AXIS_TEST_ID, height: '100%'});
chart.addSeries({...});

chart.get(Y_AXIS_TEST_ID).update({height: '80%'});

chart.get(Y_AXIS_TEST_ID).remove();

chart.addAxis({..., id: Y_AXIS_TEST_ID, height: '100%'});
chart.addSeries({...});
```

[Full JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/serhiozone/b094stkx/24/)

To reproduce the problem follow these steps:

1. Click on "Add axis with data" button.
2. Click on "Change height" button.
3. Click on "Remove" button.
4. Click on "Add axis with data" button again.

Result: The series inside the axis are cropped with clipPath generated for height of 80% axis;
Expected: brand new axis with data, that looks like in p.1

The problem can be fixed in this case, if we generate new ID everytime we create an axis.

5. Click on "Remove" button. / or refresh the JSFiddle
6. Enable "generate new ID everytime" checkbox.
7. Follow steps 1 - 4.

Is there some case to avoid kludge of generating a new ID every time axis is created?

Comment: I suggest you report this at: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues (if you have not already), just have a look at how they generally format their bug reports, using a similar style will get you an answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Update yAxis height to 100% before removing the axis:

```
$('#remove').click(() => {
    chart.get(Y_AXIS_TEST_ID).update({height: '100%'});
    chart.get(Y_AXIS_TEST_ID).remove();
})
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g6wLhsq1/

Comment: His own workaround of generating a new ID is better, since you might need to counter all options set in your example, not only height (if more options were set).

Comment: You're right. It's just another approach to solve this issue, with one option it's even simpler.